# Comparison Criterion for Atiyah - Hirzebruch Spectral Sequence

Tags: algebraic-topology, spectral-sequences

Let us denote with $E(X)$ the A-H spectral sequence associated to a CW complex $X$ and homology theory $h_*$: $$ E(X)_{pq}^2 = H_p(X, h_q(\ast))\Longrightarrow h_{p+q}(X)$$
and with $E(Y)$ the one associated to the space $Y$ and same homology theory: $$ E(Y)_{pq}^2 = H_p(Y, h_q(\ast))\Longrightarrow h_{p+q}(Y)$$
Given a map between CW-complex $f \colon X \to Y$ it is known that we have an induced map between A-H spectral sequences $$ f^{sseq} \colon E(X) \to E(Y)$$

I'm interested in applying the [Comparison Theorem](https://books.google.de/books?id=flm-dBXfZ_gC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA45&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=comparison%20theorem&f=false) (Weibel Thm 5.2.12 page 126) (i.e. verify that it can be applied)

My lecturer applied it without checking the hypothesis, since (if I've understood correctly what he said), being $f^{sseq}$ a map of spectral sequences induced by a geometrical map, everything should be fine. I tried working out the details but I have troubles in proving that the map $f^{sseq}$ is compatible with the map $$h_*(f)\colon h_*(X)\to h_*(Y)$$ since according to the definition of compatibility one can find in Weibel, this involves do some checks with the isomorphisms $$ \beta_{pq} \colon E_{pq}^{\infty} \to \dfrac{F_ph_{p+q}}{F_{p-1}h_{p+q}}$$
The problem is that I don't have any idea about how they behave.

Can someone provides me some insights on this application of the Comparison Criterion?